# Dreamweaver CS4 Code Hinting Issues

Tags: dreamweaver, cs4, code-hinting

I'm using Dreamweaver CS4 on a Mac running OS 10.6.2 and I am experiencing issues with code hinting.

Two of my issues are:

- Closing tags are not being generated after creating the open tag in the preferences I have selected. This should happen after typing the open tag's `>`.
- Attributes/functions associated with tags are not displayed after opening one, for example: If I type `<div` and then start to type an attribute of a div tag, such as class, nothing is suggested.

I've already gone through the settings several times to no avail.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bit old, but for reference, I wrote a post about this a while ago, I came across exactly the same issue: http://blog.affirmix.com/2009/05/06/code-hinting-in-the-dreamweaver-extensibility-api/